# \vspace to increase space between figures does not work

Tags: floats

I have the following the following tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, font=large]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,
            left=0.5in,right=0.5in,
            top=0.25in,bottom=0.5in,]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
\label{fig:my-figures}
\medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
\stackunder{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}{A}
\label{fig:subfig1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hspace{12ex}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
\stackunder{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}{B}
\label{fig:subfig2}
        \end{subfigure}
\vspace{20ex}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
\stackunder{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}}{C}
\label{fig:subfig3}
        \end{subfigure}
        \end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Using `\hspace` I was able to increase the space between figs. A and B. However, I cannot increase the space between them and fig. C. I used `\vspace` but it seems not to work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: you want a blank line in the source before vspace

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Thanks a lot. It was easy, but I was unable to find a solution

Comment: adding vspace in horizontal mode has a well defined behaviour but adds the space after the current line is made which is rarely where you expect. Adding it in vertical mode it adds space directly where written (this isn't really related to figures at all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

90% of questions with `\vspace` in the title can be answered by "Put a blank line before the vspace"

Adding `\vspace` in horizontal mode causes the space to be saved in a special place (a vadjust node) and it is re-inserted later after the paragraph has been broken into lines.
This is a well defined mechanism but it is hardly ever what the author intended.

Adding `\vspace` in vertical mode directly adds the space at the point written.

When writing multiple subfigures you probably don't think of it as a "paragraph" but to tex a subfigure is just a big letter and this is a paragraph going through its standard line breaking algorithm

It is easier to see what happens with normal sized letters:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


x y \vspace{2cm} z


\hrule

x y

\vspace{2cm} z

\hrule
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation David